# How to set a Chinese app name in Electron?

Tags: electron, internationalization, package.json, electron-forge, squirrel.windows

I'm using [`electron-forge`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) and [`Squirrel.Windows`](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows), if I set a Chinese name in `package.json`, such as `"name": "测试"`, it warns:

```
String does not match the pattern of "^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$".
```

So how do I set a Chinese app name in Electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're using [`electron-forge`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) and [`Squirrel.Windows`](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows), you can set a Chinese `productName` in `package.json` to achieve a Chinese app name, in your case: `"productName": "测试"`.